# UITest method always return UICollectionView Cell empty

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uitest

I have a `collectionView` with static data, with is loaded in `viewDidLoad` method. But the `UITest` gives me error because there is no cells. Here is my `UITest` method:

```
func testSelectCardAndValue(){

    app.buttons["btnPay"].tap()

    let collectionView = app.collectionViews
    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    print("Qtde : \(collectionView.cells.count)") //ALWAYS SHOWING 0
    expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: collectionView.cells.firstMatch, handler: nil)

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 20, handler: nil)
    if(app.collectionViews.cells.count > 0) {
        app.collectionViews.cells.firstMatch.tap()
    }
}
```

Here is my screenshot of the view at the exact moment that the test failed. There is data in there. What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: If you move the `print` after the `waitForExpectations ` do you still get 0?

Comment: @Chris the execution of the method stops at the waitForExpectations with the error "Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 20 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "Expect predicate `exists == 1` for object Cell"."